# Formula to calculate left and width values (based on 0% and 100% values)

Tags: math, formula

How can I find the formula that would, based on a percentage value, give me left and width values based on the following 0% and 100% values?

For 0,00 percentage, left and with values would be:

- Width: 658
- Left: 11

For 100,00 percentage, left and width values would be:

- Width: 0 (or 1)
- Left: 670

I have a gradient image, on which I apply a color to give the percentage value a visual representation.
The gradient image starts at 11 pixels (Left: 11 for 0,00%) and has a width of 659 (Left: 670 for 100,00% = 659 + 11)

The left and width values needs to be calculate dynamically based on the percentage so that the color overlays the gradient.

If the percentage is 0%, the color would overlay the whole gradient (left: 11, width: 659)

```
------------------------------
|____________________________|
0                            100
```

If the percentage is 100%, the color would not overlay the gradient at all (left: 670 which is 659 + 11, width: 1 or 0)

```
                              -
|____________________________|
0                            100
```

Comment: For the 0%, do you mean width = 648?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you're looking for can be expressed as `f(x) = ax+b`. f(x) is the width you want to get, x is the percentage, and a & b are (currently unknown) constants.

If you have the value of f(x) for two points (0 and 100 for instance), you can derive the formula like so:

```
f(0) = valueAtZero = a*0 + b
b = valueAtZero
f(100) = valueAtOneHundred = a*100 + b
valueAtOneHundred - b = a*100
a = (valueAtOneHundred - b) / 100
```

Now that you have a and b, you can solve for any percentage x you want. The process above translates into pseudocode as:

```
function getValueAtXPercent(x, valueAtZero, valueAtOneHundred):
    b = valueAtZero
    a = (valueAtOneHundred - b) / 100
    return a*x + b
```

now you can call getValueAtXPercent(50, 658, 1) and it will return your width value for 50%.

Here is a concrete implementation, in python:

```
def f(x, valueAtZero, valueAtOneHundred):
    b = valueAtZero
    a = (valueAtOneHundred - b) / 100.0
    return a*x + b

def showStats(percent):
    left = f(percent, 11, 670)
    width = f(percent, 658, 0)
    output = "At {0}%, left={1} and width={2}".format(percent, left, width)
    print output

showStats(0)
showStats(50)
showStats(100)
```

output:

```
At 0%, left=11.0 and width=658.0
At 50%, left=340.5 and width=329.0
At 100%, left=670.0 and width=0.0
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I just tried but I don't get the expected result, maybe my post is not clear enough?
getValueAtXPercent(100,00, 658, 1) would return 58,00 but expected is 670 for 'left' and 1 for 'width'

Comment: There may be a problem with your implementation. In my pseudocode, getValueAtXPercent(100,658,1) will return ((1-658)/100)*100 + 658 = 1, which is your expected value for width. Similarly, getValueAtXPercent(100, 11, 670) returns ((670-11)/100)*100 + 11 = 670, the expected value for left.

Comment: @user706058, I think I understand what you want now. I've expanded my answer.